# SQL Server 2008 - how to raise error, when trying to update locked row?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

In my application, several users have the ability to read or modify the same tables. However, when one row is modified by a user, the others should not be able to use it anymore.

I am using Transactions with **ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED**. The Problem is, that when a user updates a row in a table and another user tries to update the same row - the second Transaction will wait for the first Transaction to **ROLLBACK/COMMIT**, before it can update the row.

What i want to do is to raise an error in this Situation, for the second user - *so he does not have to wait so long*.

How can I do this??

The Problem is that the Transactions are quite large (several procedures included), so there would be a posibility of blocking some users for quite some time because of the lock.

Thank you

Comment: `READPAST`, `sp_getapplock` or hand-made logical locks.

Comment: thanks  @Ivan for the edit and the comment:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use a `NOWAIT` hint when the second user attempts his query from his own transaction:

**User one**

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE blah
```

**User two**

```
(first user's transaction still open)
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT *
FROM someTable WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE blah
```

I recall reading somewhere that only Oracle and Postgres support fail fast lock acquisitions.  If so, then the above hint might be ignored.

Comment: that is great - thanks; These TabelHints also work for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE Statements. So this solved my Problem!